# Web.Debug.config not processing substitution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web application in VS2010 with a web.config like this:

```
...
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=MyProdDb;Initial Catalog=MyCat;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPass;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
...
```

and a Web.Debug.config like this:

```
...
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices"
          connectionString="data source=MyDevDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
          xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
...
```

The project is set to create a Debug build, and when I run it in the debugger, I get `MyProdDb` rather than `MyDevDb`

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you publishing this web site, or are you strictly talking compile and run?

Comment: That's because you have "MyProdDb" on your web.config ??!?

Comment: Unfortunately, the debugger doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people have said the web.config versions only get applied at publish (MSDeploy) time. The normal way you would do things is to have your 'Debug' config in the actual web.config file and make changes to that for each of the deployment scenarios you have.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that and it solves the problem.  Makes me wonder what Web.Debug.config is for then, since Web.Release.config is the only one used in that workflow.  I have not seen setups where one would want to publish debug settings from a dev PC to an external server (I guess that could be used for publish to QA, but I have not seen it done that way).

Comment: Really the reason you may want multiples is in one of the following scenarios, You have multiple deployment environments (Test, Acceptance, Production), you need to deploy a 'debug' version to another environment to diagnose an issue (prehaps debug means you have custom errors off or something like that)

Comment: This is not true anymore, with an update from Scott Hanselman's team.  See my additional answer.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED INFORMATION**

Arbitrary XML-based .config files can now be processed, and the processing can happen at build time rather than at deployment time

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Brilliantly, the transforms can also be previewed directly in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing?

You are missing the fact that web.config transformation occurs only when you do a deployment. If you don't publish your web application you cannot expect any transformation to occur. If you just run your website locally by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> no transformation will occur. It's only when you publish the application that the transformation is performed.

Comment: OK I understand... though I must say it seems like a very unfortunate design choice.

Comment: FYI, not true anymore (with add-on from Scott Hanselman's team).  See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Web.config transformations gets processed at publish time only. When debugging (even in release mode), the basic Web.config file is being used.